# ZEND framework / form how to select all data from table with ->fetchall and adjust the datetime order to view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, smarty

I just started with ZEND Framework Forms. I want to make an easy guestbook in my first abstract project. For my guestbook i use 5 colomns in table "gastenboek". There is also one datetime field. I want to show the data in the Views like something in this order:

DATE_FORMAT(gastenboek.date,'%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') AS gastenboek_date

How can i do this in Zend framework, do i have to adjust something in the controller before fetchall?
Or can i do something after that, before i assign the array to the Views?

My controller:

```
    class GastenboekController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    {

        public function init()
        {
            /* Initialize action controller here */
        }

        public function indexAction()
        {
            $entries = new Application_Model_DbTable_Gastenboek();
            $test = $entries->fetchAll();

            $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($test);
            $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(3);
            $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->_request->getParam('page'));

            $this->view->assign('entries' ,$paginator);
        }
}
```

And Smarty Views gastenboek\index.tpl

```
<h2>Gastenboek</h2>

<table>
    {foreach from=$entries item=entry}
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Naam: {$entry.naam} {$entry.date} </strong></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>{$entry.bericht}</td>
    </tr>
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

Greetz Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date formatting is view specific, I would do it in the view itself:

```
<td><strong>Naam: {$entry.naam} {date('d-m-Y H:i', strtotime($entry.date))} </strong></th>
```